# (In)finitely many natural numbers are not the sum or difference of two perfect powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

> Are there infinitely many positive integers which are neither a sum nor a difference of
>   two perfect powers?

This question was proposed some years ago at [KoMaL](http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=A612&l=en).

It's easy to see that the odd numbers can be written as the difference of two consecutive perfect squares.

A similiar problem was posted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153427/numbers-of-the-form-am-bn) and the same problem was posted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999970/integers-neither-as-sum-nor-difference-of-perfect-powers). According to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A074981) there are many numbers that are hard (and probably open) to prove they aren't a difference of powers.

I'm looking for a proof or any reference of this result.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Given that the difference question seems to be known to be hard, and sums of two perfect powers are sparse for obvious reasons, this new question, although logically a little easier, might still be hard. Is there any reason to believe that mathematics is ready for this problem?

Comment: @znt Yes, there is. The question with difference only is an open problem. The question with difference or sum is not an open problem (open problems are not proposed at KoMaL).

Comment: If you're saying that this is a puzzle, and someone somewhere knows the answer, then some people would say that this question isn't appropriate for this site and you should take it to MSE.

Comment: I think you should email the editors (szerk@komal.hu), chances are that the problem was not posed correctly (or an April 1 joke was made). The question was asked on MSE by the way (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999970/integers-neither-as-sum-nor-difference-of-perfect-powers).

Comment: Can you be more precise about the source of your assertion "it's conjectured that only finitely many positive integers are not the difference of two perfect powers"? I don't see any indication of this in the links you provide (I don't know whether to believe it or not, I'm just confused about why you think it). I should remark that just because only finitely many terms are listed on the OEIS page doesn't mean that people believe the sequence stops there (see for example the page for the Fibonacci sequence, which stops at 39088169 although the sequence goes on).

Comment: @znt This is a research level question, that is why I posted it here. Please, read the 'comments' and 'references' from the OEIS site. They say: 'Conjectured list of positive numbers which are not of the form r^i-s^j'.

Comment: @jack: if this is a puzzle that someone knows the answer to, then some people would say that it's not appropriate for this site, whether or not it's research level. And I think that either you or I am misunderstanding the OEIS site. The sequence is defined to be the list of positive numbers not a difference of powers,  but I don't see the claim that the list is finite. Sure the list on OEIS *stops* but my point about the Fibonacci example was that of course _every_ list on OEIS stops and this is not an indication of finiteness. If I've misunderstood you, can you be more precise about a ref?

Comment: I should add that if all terms of a finite sequence on OEIS are listed, the keyword "full" is added to the sequence, and the sequence you're referring to do does not have this keyword. If a sequence is finite but not all the terms are listed, the keyword "fini" is added, and the sequence we're talking about doesn't have this one either. So I do not understand why you think that there should conjecturally only be finitely many terms in this sequence, at this point.

Comment: Aah -- your edit has shown me where the problem lies! I think that the OEIS does *not* say that everything between 426 and $10^{19}$ is a difference -- I think you've misread. Between 390 and 426, most of the numbers which are 2 mod 4 are in the list -- it can't mean this. I think the OEIS is saying that every number in the OEIS list cannot be written as a difference of two powers, such that each of the *powers* is less than $10^{19}$. I agree it's poorly-worded but this seems to me like a more reasonable interpretation. It would not surprise me if the next number in the list were 430 or 434.

Comment: I think what is conjectured at OEIS, jack, is not that only the numbers listed satisfy the property, but that all the numbers listed do satisfy the property. For any given number on the list, it is hard (and probably open) to prove that it isn't a difference of powers. Think of how hard it was to prove Catalan's Conjecture.

Comment: @znt and Gerry Myerson You are right, this interpretation makes much more sense.